# Merge files based on a date range?

Tags: pandas

My goal is to be able to look up specific information about an employee on a certain date. I have a function that works but it is pretty memory intensive when I am dealing with over 100,000 employees.

DF1 (roster):

```
employee_id | manager | effective_date | expiration_date
abc           Fred      2016-02-03     2016-03-07
abc           John      2016-03-08     2999-12-31
```

So using the dataframe above, this function would produce a dataframe which would create a row for every date between 2016-02-03 to 2016-03-08 for EACH employee_id. This means I can do `pd.merge(raw, roster, on=['employee_id', 'effective_date'])`

```
def add_roster(df, date_col):
    min_date = df[date_col].min() #min date of the raw data I am joining
    roster = df2
    current_roster = roster.groupby(['employee_id'])['effective_date'].idxmax() #max date in the roster
    rows = roster.ix[current_roster]
    rows['effective_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dt.date.today()) #makes sure there is a date up until current date
    current = pd.concat([roster, rows], ignore_index=True)
    current = current.sort_values(['avaya_id', 'effective_date'], ascending=True)
    roster = current.groupby(['employee_id']).apply(
        lambda x: x.set_index('effective_date').resample('D').first().ffill()) #this is filling the roster up so there is an entry for every date
    roster = roster.reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
    roster = roster[roster['effective_date'] >= min_date]
    return roster
```

This works but now I am dealing with a large number of employees so it seems a bit inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

There is an expiration date too in the data.

Can I do a pd.merge that says something like:

Join on `employee_id where date >= effective_date and date < expiration_date`?

I want the most efficient way to join data on a specific date.

DF2 (raw)

```
employee_id | date        | data_count_1 | data_count_2
abc           2016-02-18       10              56
abc           2016-02-28       19              102
abc           2016-06-21       5               4
```

DF3 (Desired output):

```
employee_id | date        | data_count_1 | data_count_2 | manager
abc           2016-02-18       10              56         Fred
abc           2016-02-28       19              102        Fred 
abc           2016-06-21       5               4          John
```

The manager should be Fred on 2/18 and 2/28 because it is between the effective_date and expiration_date. On 3/08, the manager for employee abc is John and there are no changes after that. This means on 6/21 the manager is John.

Comment: I edited the function. The roster is another dataframe actually. I read from a database in a separate dataframe but this dataframe only has effective and expiration dates. The raw data I am joining with is a separate dataframe but it might have data for any date. I want to be able to join based on the employee_id and date as long as the date is between the effective and expiration date.

Comment: Sure I made an edit. I am trying to look up who the manager is on a certain date which falls between the effective and expiration dates and add it to DF2 which is some example raw data. DF3 is the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `df1` is

```
  effective_date employee_id expiration_date manager
0     2016-02-03         abc      2016-03-07    Fred
1     2016-03-08         abc      2199-12-31    John
2     2016-01-01         xyz      2016-02-14   Rocco
3     2016-02-15         xyz      2016-03-14   Floyd
```

and `df2` is

```
   data_count  data_count2       date employee_id
0          10           56 2016-02-18         abc
1          19          102 2016-02-28         abc
2           5            4 2016-06-21         abc
3           9           99 2016-02-20         xyz
```

then

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz'], 
                    'manager':['Fred','John', 'Rocco', 'Floyd'],
                'effective_date':['2016-02-03', '2016-03-08', 
                                  '2016-01-01', '2016-02-15'],
                'expiration_date':['2016-03-07', '2199-12-31',
                                   '2016-02-14', '2016-03-14'], })
for col in ['effective_date', 'expiration_date']:
    df1[col] = pd.to_datetime(df1[col])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'employee_id':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz'], 
                    'date':['2016-02-18', '2016-02-28', '2016-06-21', '2016-02-20'],
                    'data_count':[10,19,5,9],
                    'data_count2':[56,102,4,99],})
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

merged = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='employee_id', how='left')
condition = ((merged['effective_date'] <= merged['date'])
             & (merged['date'] < merged['expiration_date']))
result = merged.loc[condition]
print(result)
```

yields

```
   data_count  data_count2       date employee_id effective_date expiration_date manager
0          10           56 2016-02-18         abc     2016-02-03      2016-03-07    Fred
2          19          102 2016-02-28         abc     2016-02-03      2016-03-07    Fred
5           5            4 2016-06-21         abc     2016-03-08      2199-12-31    John
7           9           99 2016-02-20         xyz     2016-02-15      2016-03-14   Floyd
```

---

Presumably the number of managers per employee will be low, so

```
merged = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='employee_id', how='left')
```

will have a size on the order by `len(df2)` times some small multiple (roughly,
the average number of managers per employee). So if `len(df2)` is on the order of
100K, then `len(merged)` will probably be less than a couple million and
should fit comfortable in memory on a standard computer.

`merged` may have a lot of rows you don't actually want -- rows where `date` is not between `effective_date` and `expiration_date`.
To select the rows you do want, form the boolean mask `condition` and use `merged.loc[condition]` to select rows where `condition` is True:

```
condition = ((merged['effective_date'] <= merged['date'])
             & (merged['date'] < merged['expiration_date']))
result = merged.loc[condition]
```

Comment: I tried something like this a while ago but I did not have the part with the merged.loc[condition]. I think this looks pretty promising, let me test it.